# Disparity between Wikipedia's "What links here" count and backlink count using recommended tool

Tags: r, mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of backlinks to a list of pages on the english wikipedia database. I first tried using the mediawiki api to collect all of the links, using the blcontinue parameter; however, when I queried certain pages (e.g., Canada) there were an inordinate amount of backlinks i.e., many, many thousand.

When I look in the "what links here" for the Canada page, and exclude redirects, there seem to be again an inordinate amount (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:WhatLinksHere/Canada&namespace=0&limit=5000&hideredirs=1). I decided that at the current time, I could just do with the total rather than the full list of links, so I used the recommended tool (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:What_links_here#Number_of_links) and queried the api for Canada, non-redirects (the default namespace is 0), effectively replicating the above query. Here's the documentation, https://dispenser.info.tm/~dispenser/cgi-bin/backlinkscount.py, and here's some sample R code:

```
bl_url <- "https://dispenser.info.tm/~dispenser/cgi-bin/backlinkscount.py"
  query_param <- list(
  title  = "Canada",
  filterredir = "nonredirects")

bbl <- GET(bl_url, query = query_param)

num_bl <- as.numeric(content(bbl))

> num_bl
[1] 353
```

here's the url produced by the call to the api:

https://dispenser.info.tm/~dispenser/cgi-bin/backlinkscount.py?title=Canada&filterredir=nonredirects

So the total returned is 353, much fewer than on the "what links here"

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one else noticed the logic for `nonredirect` and `redirect` were swapped for years.  I killed the old parameter name `filterredir`, create `filter` with the expected behavior, better error handling, and clearer instructions.

https://dispenser.info.tm/~dispenser/cgi-bin/backlinkscount.py?title=Canada&filter=nonredirects&from_namespaces=0